# Making code that can use other programs

Tags: vb.net, memory-management

Is it possible to get the memory address from "normal" programs, like it is from games for trainers?

The reason I am asking is cause I wondered it if was possible to make some code(like VB *although don't know if vb can change memory addresses tho doh*.) that uses a different program, and its functions?

The process I want to code is going to barcode library, select INSERT from the menu, then go to firer info. After that a form opens witch allows me to enter Firer Name and Shooter ID. Then when pressing OK it generates the barcode.

It would be pretty sweet if there was a way to make some code that loops through the list(for example in excel, but could be .csv as well I assume) and add all the shooters, instead of having to do it manually (There could be someone having 1000 shooters)

With the program cheat engine I was able to find the memory address for the Firer number in the form, but I had to open the form myself first.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automate existing windows programs you would probably be best using a framework that can drive them from outside. Some thing like [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/), [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or a framework designed for testing such application would probably work as well, and could be written like a program, something like [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) or microsofts [coded UI framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx).

Comment: I can imagine that that would be a lot easier. I just have a few follow up questions. 1) Using one of the programs mentioned above would require that another user would have to install that program? 2) Is it possible to make code that does what i just asked? Thanks for very speedy reply :)